# Can't remove Self Signed Certificate to use my own on Virtualmin

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, centos, virtualmin

I have installed Virtualmin on my fresh CentOS and purchased a cert from rapidSSL. I have done all the steps needed, but however, the SSL does not work and I still get the non secure thing when I visit the site.

As per the dashboard it seems I have done the correct things. http://s11.postimg.org/52e7qvwoj/ssls.png

I used an online SSL checker, https://cryptoreport.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp and the result I got was that I need to remove the default Self Signed Cert.

- Is it really a self-signed cert problem? Anyone experienced that?
- Is it possible to be a CA chaining problem? As I read on a site that Virtualmin has a buggy in that regard.
- Should the self-signed cert be removed? Or updated?
- Does Virtualmin treat self-signed certs different than the commercial ones?

Any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the answer to your question.  Nevertheless, will try to help.

I always remove the self signed certs once i import/install a valid cert from a CA.

If you used Virtualmin UI, does it not replace the old one with the new one by itself.

Also, don't forget to upload the CA's cert!

```
If your virtual server's SSL certificate is from a certificate 
authority that is not directly known to major browsers, 
you may need to upload the CA's certificate using this form.
```